# While creating during creating new rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Could not load OpenSSL.
You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL
using RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.

Comment: What exactly do you find unclear about the error message? It even points you to instructions on how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is in the error message. Change '**https**://rubygems.org' to '**http**://rubygems.org'. That should get it working.

Also, if you are using Ubuntu for your operating system, I've never found a better tutorial for installing ruby, rails, and rvm than http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/ . Just follow it exactly and you shouldn't have any problems.

If you're not on Ubuntu and want a more detailed answer, you need to tell us:
 - What Operating System **and version** you are using
 - What version of rails and ruby you want to install